# Redis + Lua. Can I return result without storing it in memory?

Tags: database, lua, redis

I have the following Lua script executed in Redis environment:

```
    local result = {}
    local comment_ids = redis.call('smembers', 'comment:all')
    for _, key in ipairs(comment_ids) do
        local comment_text = ...
        local article_name = ...
        local user_name = ...

        result[#result+1] = {article_name, user_name, comment_text}
    end
    return result
```

Basicly, what happens here is we fill 'result' table with some aggregated data (article_name, user_name, comment_text) and return it.

As far as I understand this table will be fully stored in memory until return statement.

**My main question is, can I return data row by row, without storing full response in memory?**

*And also, is it appropriate to use Lua scripts for aggregation purposes? (Like I am trying to do it here).*
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not stream the result.

WRT the also - it is very appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for help! I've just started experimenting with Redis and Lua, so I don't know almost anything about common practises in this area,

Comment: Everybody starts sometime, and you seem to be on the right path.